# ViewFlipper not flipping with child listview

Tags: android, viewflipper

ViewFlipper is not working when swiping. If i put some other view instead of list view, flipping works fine. Is there any other code i should add for a listview? And scroll view inside view flipper also not working for me :(
This is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/vf"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

This is my class code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
    private Animation slideLeftIn;
    private Animation slideLeftOut;
    private Animation slideRightIn;
    private Animation slideRightOut;
    private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    private ListView lv;
    private String[] city = { "Indore", "Bhopal", "Khargone", "Ujjain",
        "Nasik", "Pune", "Delhi", "Mumbai", "Noida", "Hyderabad",
        "Banglore", "Ajmer", "Goa", "Jaipur", "Nagpur", "" };
    private String[] country = { "India", "Bhutan", "Kuwait", "USA", };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List01);
        ListView lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List02);

        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
        slideLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_in);
        slideLeftOut = AnimationUtils
                .loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_out);
        slideRightIn = AnimationUtils
                .loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_in);
        slideRightOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.slide_right_out);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city));
        lv2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, country));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // user clicked a list item, make it "selected"
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item Clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // selectedAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
            }
        });
        lv2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // user clicked a list item, make it "selected"
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item List2 Clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // selectedAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
            }
        });
    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
                    viewFlipper.showNext();
                } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
                    viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

**Override dispatchTouchEvent instead of onTouchEvent makes both scroll view and gesture working fine.**

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution of using dispatchTouchEvent instead of onTouchEvent helped me.

Comment: Thanks, it works great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrolling is not taking effect, as you have already overrided gestures, so, you also need to take scroll effect manually, in the case.

Comment: How to take scroll effect manually? Can you post some code eamples?

Comment: no, I don't have example or sample, you just google and definitely you will get something good.