# Flip between Views Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewflipper

I am coding an application that has an activity that can supply the end user with data in two formats a bar graph view using the Teechart api (available here: http://www.steema.com/teechart/mobile) and a listview native in android. Currently I have some logic like so

first i Initialize a `boolean flag = true;`

I then use this button logic to change between views.

```
OnClickListener changeViewListener = new OnClickListener(){

  public void onClick(View v){
    if(!flag){
       listLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       chartView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       changeView.setText("List");
       flag = true;
    }else{
       listLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       chartView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       changeView.setText("Graph");
       flag = false;
    }
  }
};
```

This code works great and gives me no trouble, I am just questioning whether this can be done a better way such as using a view flipper? And if so how do I implement the view flipper code to switch between these two views?

Or should I be using fragments for each view? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: tutorial viewFlipper Android : http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-viewflipper http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-dog-limps-into-a-saloon-a-tutorial-on-androids-viewflipper-widget/634

Comment: that works fine, if you never worked before with fragments and this application does not have a specific requirement of working on tablets and phone don't worry about them. I would just delete the flag and use `(listLayout.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE` instead

Comment: is using a flag going to eat up more memory because im adding another variable? I want this to be as smooth as possible.

Comment: Also I do have tablet layouts for the application and they are not consistent with the phone layouts. Should i be reading up on fragments if I want this UI to be smooth?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this could be of help to you:
[Animate between Views](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2010/11/android-animate-between-views.html)

It gives a generic example, may be you can tweak it to get the flip effect you want.

**Update:**
That tutorial also gives links to various Animation docs. From that, I think you can use [Rotate Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html#RotateAnimation%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) to create the flip effect. You can give the angle of rotation and the pivot about which to rotate the view.

The concept is that you rotate one view **out** and rotate **in** the other view.

**Update:**

View Flipper is an implementation of Animating between views. The above method I posted was generic, you can toy around with values and create animations with you having much more finer control. You can create transitions between Views that others may never have tried.

Steps for View Flipper:

**1.** In View Flipper, you define a Flipper element in your Layout XML file. To this flipper element, you add two child elements, which could simply be two Views OR two Layouts OR one View and one Layout. The View Flipper flips between these two Views you have defined.

**2.** Once you have created this much in XML, you then create four animation rules under `/res/anim` for the following types of entry and exit transitions:

**a.** Left In

**b.** Left Out

**c.** Right In

**d.** Right Out

**3.** After 1 and 2, you now add Touch or Gesture listeners in your code, to listen for Touch and Listen events. Inside these listeners, you then initiate the animation using `vf.setInAnimation()` or `vf.setOutAnimation()`, where `vf` is your ViewFlipper instance.

You can find complete code over here:

**1.** [View Flipper Tutorial 1](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-dog-limps-into-a-saloon-a-tutorial-on-androids-viewflipper-widget/634)

**2.** [View Flipper Tutorial 2](http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/android-practice-viewflipper-sample/)

**Update:**
A few tweaks have to be made to make View Flipper work with ListView. I found this other SO question where the same problem was solved with a minor edit. Check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924817/viewflipper-not-flipping-with-child-listview).

Comment: Is this how view flipper works too? It seems like if i just add an animation to my two layouts i can get this effect without having to change a lot of code.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain about View Flipper and also given two tutorial links with complete code samples. Also explained the difference between View Flipper and general Animations.

Comment: If i use this, since both views are scrollable there is no way to flip the view? How do i implement a view flipper on a listview?

Comment: Another SO question solved the same problem. I've posted the link in the updated answer. See if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have two views that you want to switch between, this approach is good enough. However, you can use a view pager to implement this Such an approach would particularly be useful if you have several views so that you don't render them all at once and waste memory. ViewPager will manage when to create and destroy views.

1. Define in layout

   ```
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   ```
2. Create an adapter

   ```
   class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

       public int getCount() {
           return 2;
       }

       public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(
                   Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

           // Inflate the correct view based on position
           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayoutHere, null);

           // ... Setup the view

           ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
           return view;
       }

       @Override
       public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
           ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
           return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
       }

       @Override
       public Parcelable saveState() {
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Set the adapter

   ```
   ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
   viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter());
   ```

Now on button click, you can set the current item of view pager.

```
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If this is a good enough approach I will just leave it an add the animations to make it look like the views are flipping in and out. Its only going to be two views so I wont be wasting much memory since the data is pulled from the local db. If my requirements change such as accessing a webservice using HTTPTransportSE or something I will reconsider changing my approach to something like this. Again thanks.